# Eclipse Neon - Javascript Console Output not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, eclipse, console

I'm developing a PHP project which utilizes Javascript with jquery for a number of functions (particularly authentication/api calls). The long and short of my problem is that I cannot get Javascript console logs to appear in the eclipse console. At all.

Not only this, but some of my functions work...sometimes. I'm trying to debug the cause of this, but without any form of logging occurring, it's extremely difficult.

How do I configure my Eclipse Neon PHP project to output Javascript console logs?

Edit: The project is a PHP Web Application. I'm currently running a local PHP server for the project via the php command `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: Do you create a web application? I f yes, then the JavaScript `console.log()` function sends lines to the browser console, which is in the devtools in your browser, not Eclipse.

Comment: I am indeed creating a web application, I just edited my original post to reflect that information. When I run the application from eclipse it shows the page in the IDE, not a separate browser.

Is there a way to view the Dev Tools console via eclipse, or will I just need to debug via the browser?

Comment: As I know, Eclipse is using a closed browser which is not letting you use the devtools, but I'm doing research right now...

Comment: Thank you. I've been using the Browser Dev tools, and this accomplishes what I need as it is.

Comment: It though doesn't look like you can use the Eclipse Dev Tools. Should I create an answer you can accept?

Comment: Sure! Your answer serves the purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript built-in function `console.log(message);` logs the given message to the console in the browser window, which is accessible via the developer tools of your browser.

If you open your webapp via the built-in Eclipse browser, you do not have access to those tools, just because Eclipse is using a closed, minified browser (just like the browser widget for QT or Visual C# WinForms or even a distributed [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) app).

Using the Eclipse browser is not really helpful when trying to debug webapps, because you can't even see loading times of the pages and so on.